# Get new field address in the payment module (capture function). M2.2.4

Tags: magento2, address

I added a new field (neighborhood) at the client's address. Everything is working.

But, I need to get this value from my payment module. I created the capture ($payment) function.

With the $payment->getOrder()->getShippingAddress() object I can not get the getData->('neighborhood').

To add the "neighborhood" field, I created a module using "extension_attributes".

The getShippingAddress uses the "Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address". I need to add the getData('neighborhood') or getExtensionAttributes->getNeighborhood()

Can someone help me?

Magento 2.2.4

Comment: Does this field store the value in the database?

Comment: @EvgeniyKapelko Yes! entity_id = 164. The "Neighborhood" field appears in the client forms in the frontend and also in adminhtml. Everything is working. But, I can not make the "neighborhood" field return in the $payment->getOrder() ->getShippingAddress().